# Dictionary Comprehension from List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dict as noted below.

```
d1 = [{'key':'a', 'val':1}, {'key':'a', 'val':2}, {'key':'b', 'val':10}, {'key':'b', 'val':20}, {'key':'b', 'val':30}]
```

The ask is to create a new dict whose keys are values of 'key' keys and values are list made up of values whose keys are 'key'. So the final output would be like:

```
d1_parsed = {'a':[1, 2], 'b':[10, 20, 30]}
```

I was able to get that created using a for loop but was trying to see if there was a way to do that using dict comprehension.

I tried this but did not get me the results that I was looking for

```
d1_parsed = {rec['key']:[].append(rec['val']) for rec in d1}

d1_parsed = {'a': None, 'b': None}
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: There is no *good* way to do this with a dictionary comprehension. Comprehension constructs are for expressing mapping/filtering operations, you are doing an aggregation. You can trivially do the inefficient `{d['key']:[x['val'] for x in d1 if x['key'] == d['key']] for d in d1}` but that makes your algorithm quadratic time when it doesn't have to be.

Comment: This may sound facetious but isn’t: if it’s so difficult why bother? If you succeed you won’t be able to debug it if it stops working (whereas debugging a for loop is easy), and what if someone else comes along to look at/update/modify your amazing one-liner - they might have to expand it out to for loop(s) to understand it.

Comment: `d1_parsed = {d['key']: [x['val'] for x in d1 if x['key']==d['key']] for d in d1}` is my two pence - don't do this though